# Laravel if field required, don't return error for each value?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have a very large registration form.

```
'username_c'        => 'required|unique:contacts_cstm',
'password'          => 'required|min:6',
'email'             => 'required|email',
'password_repeat'   => 'required|same:password',
'first_name'        => 'required',
'last_name'         => 'required',
'rsa'               => 'required',
```

And so on (another 15 fields)...

The problem is if the form is submitted with nothing entered, about 20 different errors are returned (as they should be).

Except, it would be nice if any of the required fields is *NOT* entered, to spit back one error saying "All fields are required" or something similar.

I've read through Laravel's docs. on this and didn't find anything.  Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Try doing [custom error messages](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-error-messages) although what this will basically do is just replace the default error message.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of your fields in the `$rules` array are required, you should be able to do something as simple as an `array_filter($required_fields_input)`, compare the length against that of your `$required_rules` and redirect back with a single error message/alert.

See code example below. I tried to keep it simple/commented enough...

Not tested at all ... but theoretically! .... ;)

```
class YourController {

    // ...

    public function postFormData()
    {
        $rules = [
            // ...
            'first_name'        => 'required',
            'last_name'         => 'required',
            'rsa'               => 'required'
            // ...
        ];

        // Assuming all fields in $rules are "required"
        $required_fields       = array_keys($rules);
        $required_fields_input = Input::only($required_fields);

        // Clean out all empty/null fields
        $input_not_empty       = array_filter($required_fields_input);
        if (count($input_not_empty) < count($required_fields))
        {
            $fill_them_all_in_message = "Please fill in all required fields.";
            return Redirect::back()->withMessage($fill_them_all_in_message);
        }

        /**
         * All required fields present
         * Continue as usual ..
         * .. Validate/Respond/etc...
         */
    }

    //...
}
```

I think that pretty much covers your main concern of

a.) Avoiding 15 messages that say "XYZ field is required" ....

b.) Still allowing for the rest of the validation/processing to continue as usual.

Hope that helps!